# linq query on multiple columns from a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

I have a list of configuration objects which contains three fields: type, minvalue and maxvalue. I also have a campaign table and its configuration are stored in the configuration table. Campaign configuration table contains four columns: type, minvalue, maxvalue and campaignid. I want to join the list of configuration from the user with the configuration table to select the most appropriate campaign? Can anyone let me know how to do this using linq ?

```
Domain Entity Models:

public class Configuration
{
    public int Type { get; set; }       

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string ValueMax { get; set; }    

    public Campaign Campaign { get; set; }        
}

public class Campaign
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Configuration> Configuration { get; set; }
}

Client Request Models:

public class FiltersVM
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ValueMax { get; set; }
}

public class FilterRequest
{ 
    public List<FiltersVM>  Filters { get; set; }
}
```

I need a list of campaign Id's which exactly match the configurations like
1, 2, 3

Comment: Have you tried any query to achieve this?

Comment: You code is circular.  Configuration => Campaign and Campaign => Configuration.

Comment: What is "the list of configuration from the user"?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you want is to find which Campaigns have a specific configuration, right?
You could select all configurations that satisfy your query and then navigate to its Campaign.

```
Configuration.Where(c=> c.Type == type && Value == value && ValueMax == valueMax).Select(c=> c.Campaign.Id)
```